# Not able to validate field in django restframeork , How do i overcome of this kind error

Tags: python, django, django-validation, django-rest-framework

**serializers.py**

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
  city = CitiesSerializers()
  state = StatesSerializers()
  country = CountrySerializes()

class Meta:
    model = User
    fields = ('url', 'username', 'email', 'groups', 'first_name',    'last_name', 'company_name', 'email2', 'address',
              'country', 'state', 'city', 'pincode', 'phone_no1', 'phone_no2', )`class CountrySerializes(serializers.ModelSerializer):
class Meta:
    model = Countries
    fields = ('__all__')


class StatesSerializers(serializers.ModelSerializer):
  class Meta:
    model = States
    fields = ('__all__')


class CitiesSerializers(serializers.ModelSerializer):
  class Meta:
    model = Cities
    fields = ('__all__')  `
```

**views.py**

```
if serialized.is_valid():
    User.objects.create_user(company_name=company_name, email2=email2, address=address, country_id=country,
                             state_id=state, city_id=city, pincode=pincode, phone_no1=phone_no1,
                             phone_no2=phone_no2, password=password, username=username, email=email,
                             first_name=first_name, last_name=last_name, is_active=is_active)
    return Response({'status': 1, "message": "User created with this detail"}, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
else:
    return Response(serialized._errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

**response in REST**

```
{"city":["This field is required."],"state":["This field is required."],"country":["This field is required."]}
```

Above I have mentioned code for DRF application and **I am not able to save user without validation!**

Any help regarding the same would be appreciated.

Comment: why do you want to save the object without validation? why not just make those field optional?

Comment: @v1k45 how can i opt it out ? i also need it in db

Comment: all you need to do it pass `required=False` to the field in your serializer. e.g. `city = CitiesSerializers(required=False)`

Comment: see problem is that i have send id in from form view. I have recived key in  POST but not able to store using only primary key.

Comment: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'Countries' `CitiesSerializers(required=False)` after required false

Comment: post the full traceback and update your question to be clear about the problem you are facing.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139498/discussion-between-hardik-gajjar-and-v1k45).